# How can I format the decimal value without decimal?

Tags: sql, oracle

eg 18.45 should be 00000000001845000
datatype suppose number(x,5) so last five digits are for precision

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use the V format model element; [from the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C):

> | Element | Example | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | V | 999V99 | Returns a value multiplied by 10n (and if necessary, round it up), where n is the number of 9's after the V. |

So you can do:

```
select to_char(18.45, '000000000000V00000') from dual;

TO_CHAR(18.45,'000000000000V00000')
-----------------------------------
 00000000001845000
```

or without the leading space (which is a placehold for a minus sign in case there are negative values):

```
select to_char(18.45, 'FM000000000000V00000') from dual;

TO_CHAR(18.45,'FM000000000000V00000')
-------------------------------------
00000000001845000
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2626c4c4e8bc5f49cd8a8c8043a4e408)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can multiply for 100000 the given number:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(18.45 * 100000, '00000000000000000') FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
SELECT REPLACE(TO_CHAR(18.45, 'FM000000000000D00000', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,'''), '.', '') FROM DUAL;
```

The `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS`makes sure the decimal separator is a `.` regardless what the session is configured. This way we're safe to remove it from the resulting string with the `replace` function.

The `FM` is used to suppress the leading space character.